# Counting occurrence of a gender in a dataframe by age

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like

```
age gender
69  M
29  F
61  F
66  F
52  M
```

What I would like to know is how many males and females there are in each age group.  Is there somehow I could use `groupby` to group the data by age and then use `agg` to count the instances of male and female?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can groupby age AND gender:

```
df.groupby(['age','gender']).size()
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

will give

```
age  gender
69   M       1
29   F       1
61   F       1
66   F       1
52   M       1
```

Comment: Hm, yea this does work.  I was hoping to have Males and Females as columns instead.  I guess I could do that with a `pivot`, right?  EDIT: Accomplished what I wanted by adding `unstack('gender')` to your answer.  Thanks